# displaying the '£' and '€' symbol using XSL

Tags: xslt

I'm reading a data source, and then applying an xsl transform to the text that comes out and all the £ and € symbols are being stripped.

Am I missing something obvious? I've tried changing the encoding to iso-8859-1 to no avail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="Subject"/>
    <xsl:param name="DateString"/>
    <xsl:param name="CurrentSiteUrl"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="posts>
        <xsl:variable name="postcount" select="count(content)"/>
        <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;utf-8" />
            </head>
```

Comment: A good part of the XSLT script is apparently missing...

Comment: Can you provide actual examples? I really do not see why a XSLT processor would treat these signs different from any other Unicode character.

Comment: Also, check that the *origin* document is well-formed (which includes that its encoding is correct).

Comment: The content attribute in the meta element should be "text/html;charset=utf-8", but that might not fix it as browsers probably can recover from that mistake.

Comment: Why don't you select an answer as the solution?

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way will be to use [Numeric Character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.1).

`&#163;` for `£`
`&#8364;` for `€`

Comment: This works for Fonet (by griffm) v1.0.0. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try using &eur; and &#163; to output those symbols.

Comment: &eur; only works in HTML, not XML (at least not without a DTD).

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something obvious? I've tried changing the encoding to iso-8859-1 to no avail.

That won't work as ‘€’ isn't in iso-8859-1

```
<xsl:output encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

just a hunch but could you do

```
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
```

I don't know if the attributes of xsl:output are concatinated or overridden.

You will probably find that the entities come out encoded anyways.

Comment: iirc, the euro character exists in iso-8859-15 though, the modern replacement for iso-8859-1.

Comment: Yep - ISO-8859-15 is the charset for the Euro, but the Euro isn't the only change (so double check you don't need any of the changed characters). Wikipedia's got a summary of the differences at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15

Answer (score 0):

Use £ and € characters directly. That's what UTF-8 is for.

Just make sure you're sending XML files with proper MIME type. Often used [`text/xml` overrides encoding in `<?xml ?>` declaration](http://diveintomark.org/archives/2004/02/13/xml-media-types)!
Configure server to always use `application/xml` if it doesn't do that yet.

You've got error in HTML encoding declaration. `<meta>` should contain:
`text/html;`**`charset=`**`UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem (with the euro-symbol). The problem is hardcoded in the FONET.DLL. In the class `TrueTypeFont` method `MapCharacter` is written as:

```
public override ushort MapCharacter(char c) 
{
    if (c > Byte.MaxValue) 
        return (ushort) FirstChar;
    return mapping.MapCharacter(c);
}
```

So any character with a value greater than 255 will be "ignored". I downloaded the sources (from https://fonet.codeplex.com/) and modified the method to:

```
public override ushort MapCharacter(char c) 
{
    return mapping.MapCharacter(c);
}
```

Using this library with this new method, the euro-symbol magically became visible!